# jQuery blur&focus in IE or Chrome difference

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer

```html
<html>
<head><title>asdf</title></head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="WTF">

<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#WTF").blur(function () {
        if($("#WTF").val() !== "WTF"){
            alert("WTF!");
            $("#WTF").focus();
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Like this code. 
If open in IE, alert can be trigger once correctly before you next activate the blur event. But open in Chrome, you can see the alert endless trigger. 
Why? And how do let Chrome to activate the event correctly?

Comment: So in chrome, the focus remains on `input` after the `alert` and hence your `blur` gets fired repeatedly. What's your requirement? What you wanna do on the `input`?

Comment: Emmm, I want to validate the input value when the input loses the focus. If not pass, remind the input error by alert. Finally focus back the input. —— like this code.

Comment: And I want to konw why is IE and Chrome handle this differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing you mentioned is a known bug in Chrome and you can read more about it [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/2LqXp2DMIIs)

Instead of `alert`, you can add an error `class` to indicate user about the error:

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid #d00;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>asdf</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="WTF">

  <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $("#WTF").blur(function() {
      if ($(this).val() !== "WTF") {
        $(this).addClass('error');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('error');
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```